# selecting a range of lines from command line

Tags: command-line, visual-mode

I need to (visual) select a range of lines from command line.

For example the following command `:?^\s*for?+,/^\s*end/- p` prints all lines contained between a `for` and `end` (exclusive way). Instead of performing the printing operation I would like to switch to visual mode with those lines highlighted. I searched in the manual but I couldn't find such an ex-command.

Comment: Do you mean "exclusive"?

Comment: you're right! I edited the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The boundaries of a visual mode selection are defined by the `<` and `>` marks.

Thus, the following command will enter visual mode with lines 5 through 10 (inclusive) selected:

```
 :5mark < | 10mark > | normal gvV
```

- `:5mark <` sets the start of the selection to line 5,
- `:10mark >` sets the end of the selection to line 10,
- `gv` enters visual mode with the area defined above selected,
- `V` makes the selection linewise.

You can pass any Vim range into the `:mark` command: the following will enter visual mode using the regular expressions `foo` and `bar` to define the boundaries of the selection area:

```
:execute search("foo") . "mark <" | execute search("bar") . "mark >" | normal gvV
```

The following command is a simpler version of the above, but is dependent on cursor position:

```
/foo/mark < | /bar/mark > | normal gvV
```

For more explanation, see:

- [`:help mark-motions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions)
- [`:help :mark`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:mark)
- [`:help ranges`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges)
- [`:help gv`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#gv)
- [`:help v_V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#v_V)
- [`:help :execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute)
- [`:help search()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#search())
- [`help expr-.`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-.)

Comment: Thanks! I solved with:
`?^\s*for?+ mark < | /^\s*end/- mark > | norm gv`

Comment: @nicmus Ah yes, that's simpler for your specific use. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just for the sake of any future readers that might be wondering, the `+` and `-` in @nicmus's comment are adjusting the ranges in order to make the selection *not* include the lines that match the regular expressions. (See `:help range`)

Comment: The [`.` concatenation operator](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-.) really threw me off so here's an example if someone feels the same: `:execute "l" . "s"` will produce the same output as [`:ls`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:buffers).

Comment: To visually select the entire buffer: `:execute "1mark < | " line('$')"mark > | normal gvV"`. (With help from the [_Execute_ chapter of Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html).)